# Is there any way that I can let the HapticGenerator work on any media playing on a device?

Tags: java, android, haptic-feedback

So my task is simple. I have a Pixel 7 and I love how it vibrates to the ringtones accordingly.
I'm an app developer and I want to implement the hapticgenerator to any media currently playing.
I know that there are ways like making my own Mediaplayer or sth like that, but I want it to work like an equalizer.

I already saw an example on Github like [this](https://github.com/mbaril/AndroidHapticGenerator) and many more but they don't really do much and I want it so that the haptic motor works like a subwoofer, that always vibrates, no matter what you play on your phone, like the IPhones do(if I know it right).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.